# What mean that a `Bond` has no bid-ask value?

Tags: bonds, bid-ask

From what I've seen, most Bonds have no `bid`-`ask` value.

What does that mean exactly?

Supposition 1): Nobody is trying to buy or sell this Bond. In this case, which is a good value to estimate the Bond?

Supposition 2): What about the "first time" the company is selling the bond? How does that appear in the `bid` value?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the bonds you are looking at.  Are they government or corporate bonds?  Bond markets are very liquid, so if there are no bid/ask prices then they may be very high risk bonds with poor credit ratings and little interest/liquidity.  Certainly "most" active bonds will have bid/ask prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this probably depends on where you are getting a quote.  I have brokerage accounts where there is no bid/ask.  That's because the broker is not providing a live market.  If you buy, you buy at the price that they have posted.  If you sell, you ask them for a quote and then either take it or leave it.  I'm pretty sure that in these cases the broker is actually taking the other side of the trade in every case rather than matching buyers to sellers, but that's supposition on my part.